# Opening file in Append mode : using open() API

Tags: c, unix

i am trying to open a file in append mode using open() api call , however following code is not working ! Its not writing anything to file! here is my code :

[image]

Comment: Also, what is the output fromr running your program under strace? How does it fail?

Comment: Did you check what is the value `n` returned from `write`? use printf to print it out and then check. Also, `close` the file after you have written to it.

Comment: @Pete855217, low-level I/O does not buffer; barring a power failure, the data is committed to the file once write() completes successfully

Comment: its showing same contents even after "./a.out file1" , just checked the value of n , it is -1 ! :(

Comment: `errno` and `strerror()` would be an option as well. But @bdonlan is right - you should really start accepting answers to your other 7 questions...

Comment: @bdonlan,yes hereafter i will do it ! thanks

Comment: that's a pity that this question has the code as image.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`O_APPEND` is not a mode by itself; it's a flag. Since the value of `O_RDONLY` is 0, it's like you're trying to open the file read-only but for append, which is nonsense. Use `O_WRONLY|O_APPEND` or `O_RDWR|O_APPEND`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, using open without any of `O_RDONLY`, `O_RDWR`, or `O_WRONLY` is undefined behavior. In the specific case of Linux, `O_RDONLY = 0`, so it happens to turn out that way though.

Comment: As far as I know, `O_RDONLY` is 0 on all historical implementations.

Comment: The POSIX spec calls it a mode; https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fopen.html.  Just saying ...